# Tail only the output of a command

Tags: bash, tail

I am just simply trying to run `gvm-setup` to configure OpenVAS. Since the installation is 100% unattended and doesn't require any user input, I am simply just trying to tail the last 2 lines to a file.

If I run the following:

```
gvm-setup | tee ~/.openvas_install.txt
```

then it sends the whole output to the file, as expected. This file is a whole 12MB large and I only need the last 2 lines of it to capture the password that gets presented to the user at the end of the configuration process.

How can I go about this? I realize that I can just simply `tail` the large 12MB file as an alternative, but I'm wondering if there's something like this that would work:

```
gvm-setup | tail -n 2 output_file.txt
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
[*] Checking Default scanner
08b69003-5fc2-4037-a479-93b440211c73  OpenVAS  /var/run/ospd/ospd.sock  0  OpenVAS Default

[+] Done
[*] Please note the password for the admin user
[*] User created with password 'd6ae47e5-26d0-4a85-a0ce-99b9cb3fd09d'.
```

and I just simply need to capture the randomly generated password.

Comment: What example info is output (data labels or some other data, the password obviously not needed) on the last 2 lines? ... may be something to pipe to ack or grep to fetch.

Comment: Just updated the overall post. That's a really great idea, actually. Thanks so much for the suggestion!

Comment: Then maybe something like `gvm-setup | ack 'User created with password'` ?  Or `grep` if `ack` is not preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If you need both the log file and the tail output then  you should use 2 separate commands line this

```
gvm-setup >~/.openvas_install.txt
tail -n 2 ~/.openvas_install.txt
```

Because when passing a file to `tail` then it knows that it can get file size and seek to the end of the file immediately. If you pipe the output to `tail` then it has to actually consume that huge amount of data before receiving the end of pipe and prints out the data

Of course `tee` also works because it saves the output to file and to the next command in the pipe, but it'll be far less efficient

```
gvm-setup | tee ~/.openvas_install.txt | tail -n 2
```